# Python - Problem with saving as '.csv' extension

Tags: python-3.x

Functioning code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pyautogui
import csv

url = 'https://url~~'
res = requests.get(url)
html = res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
total = soup.select('.gall_title')

searchList = []
contentList = []

for i in total:
    searchList.append("https://url~~" + i.attrs['href'])

for i in searchList:
    res2 = requests.get(i)
    html2 = res2.text
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'html.parser')
    content_h = soup2.select('h3 > span.title_subject')
    contentList.append(content_h)
print(contentList)


#save csv

f = open(1.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
csvWriter = csv.writer(f)
for i in contentList:
   csvWriter.writerow(i)
f.close()
```

★Result★

```
print(contentList):
# [[<span class="title_subject">tomato</span>], [<span class="title_subject">apple</span>]]
```

Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggYke.png)

Non-functioning code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pyautogui
import csv

url = 'https://url~~'
res = requests.get(url)
html = res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
total = soup.select('.gall_title')

searchList = []
contentList = []

for i in total:
    searchList.append("https://url~~" + i.attrs['href'])

for i in searchList:
    res2 = requests.get(i)
    html2 = res2.text
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'html.parser')
    content_h = str(soup2.select('h3 > span.title_subject')) // only changed
    contentList.append(content_h)
print(contentList)


#save csv

f = open(1.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
csvWriter = csv.writer(f)
for i in contentList:
   csvWriter.writerow(i)
f.close()
```

★Result★
print(contentList):
['[tomato]', '[apple]']

Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO5TK.png)

How can I remove the issue where strings are being saved one character at a time in a '.csv' file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`soup2.select('h3 > span.title_subject')` gives you the whole HTML tag. Extract its string value with `.string`:

```
strings = [x.string for x in soup2.select('h3 > span.title_subject')]
```

Comment: AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'string'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: I use select() instead of find().

Comment: Right, you get a list/set of results. Each must be converted to a string separately. I updated the answer.